# Calculation ensemble average by using python

Tags: python

I would like to calculate ensemble average for my txt file which has two columns, the first one is time and second one is the parameter that I want to calculate ensemble average, by python.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Actually I have not written any code yet. I know that the ensemble average can be illustrated by this equation in statistics language: E[X(t)]=∫∞−∞x∗pX(t)(x)dx Also, I have noticed that to implement by any programming language, E(x) can be defined as ∑xi*f(xi) which the f(xi) is the PDF, probability density function, of X. I do not exactly know how to implement this equation for my data.